# Zipping a large amount of data into an output stream without loading all the data into memory first in C#

Tags: c#, compression, filestream

I have a C# program that generates a bunch of short (10 seconds or so) video files. These are stored in an azure file storage blob. I want the user to be able to download these files at a later date as a zip. However, it would take a substantial amount of memory to load the entire collection of video files into memory to create the zip. I was wondering if it is possible to pull data from a stream into memory, zip encode it, output it to another stream, and dispose of it before moving onto the next segment of data.

Lets say the user has generated 100 10mb videos. If possible, this would allow me to send the zip to the user without first loading the entire 1GB of footage into memory (or storing the entire zip in memory after the fact).

The individual videos are pretty small, so if I need to load an entire file into memory at a time, that is fine as long as I can remove it from memory after it has been encoded and transmitted before moving onto the next file

Comment: I think if you use the [.NET `ZipArchive` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0) you are good to go.

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web application? Basically, is your application a middle man between the data storage and client or is it the client?

Comment: @Xerillio it is the backend for a web application. it is the middle man between the data storage and the client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible to stream in files, not requiring even any of those to be entirely in memory at any one time, and to compress, stream out, and transmit a zip file containing those, without holding the entire zip file either in memory or mass storage. The zip format is designed to be streamable. However I am not aware of a library that will do that for you.

[`ZipFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=net-6.0#system-io-compression-zipfile-createfromdirectory(system-string-system-string)) would require saving the entire zip file before transmitting it. If you're ok with saving the zip file in mass storage (not memory) before transmitting, then use `ZipFile`.

To write your own zip streamer, you would need to generate the zip file format manually. The zip format is documented [here](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). You can use  [`DeflateStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream?view=net-6.0) to do the actual compression and [`Crc32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.hashing.crc32?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to compute the CRC-32s. You would transmit the local header before each file's compressed data, followed by a data descriptor after each. You would save the local header information in memory as you go along, and then transmit the central directory and end record after all of the local entries.

zip is a relatively straightforward format, so while it would take a little bit of work, it is definitely doable.

So I went and did it. See [zipflow](https://github.com/madler/zipflow).

Comment: hm. I will implement this myself but its odd there isnt a library that can handle this. This seems like it'd be a relatively common problem any time you want a user to be able to download a zip of their data for an example

Comment: Actually, I went and implemented it. I should be posting it soon on GitHub.

Comment: @GradynWursten See https://github.com/madler/zipflow